# Синхронизировать массивы

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите мне пожалуйста как только начал учить php и уже вот непонятное задание, массивы в php имеют несколько иную структуру чем в других языках программирования поэтому не могу полностью понять, что и как надо сделать в задании.

Создать 2 массива:
города (3), районы
районы, улицы, дома.
Вывести в таблицу с синхронизацией данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот уже есть заготовка массивов но как их синхронизировать так как в таблице не знаю

```
$first = [
    'city 1' => ['area 11', 'area 12', 'area 13'],
    'city 2' => ['area 21', 'area 22', 'area 23', 'area 24'],
    'city 3' => ['area 31']
];


$second = [
    'area 11' => 'улица 111#дом 211#дом 311#улица 411#дом 511',
    'area 12' => 'улица 112#дом 212#дом 312#улица 412#дом 512',
    'area 13' => 'улица 113#дом 213#дом 313#улица 413#дом 513',
    'area 21' => 'улица 121#дом 221#дом 321#улица 421#дом 521',
    'area 22' => 'улица 122#дом 222#дом 322#улица 422#дом 522',
    'area 31' => 'улица 131#дом 231#дом 331#улица 431#дом 531'
];
```

Comment: А что имеется в виду под синхронизировать?

Comment: @Сергей, работать при выводе в таблицу одновременно с двумя массивами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заголовки и доводку до ума оставлю вам в качестве домашнего задания. Но как-то вот так, хотя зачем хранить все в разных массивах ума не приложу:

```
<?php
$first = [
    'city 1' => ['area 11', 'area 12', 'area 13'],
    'city 2' => ['area 21', 'area 22', 'area 23', 'area 24'],
    'city 3' => ['area 31']
];


$second = [
    'area 11' => ['улица 111', 'дом 212', 'дом 212', 'дом 212'],
    'area 12' => ['улица 4', 'дом 21', 'дом 12'],
    'area 21' => ['улица 5', 'дом 7' ],
    'area 31' => []
];

?>

<table border="1">

    <?php

    foreach ($first as $city => $areas){
        $isFirst = true;
        foreach ($areas as $area){
            echo "<tr>";
            if($isFirst){
                echo "<td>{$city}</td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
            $isFirst = false;
            echo "<td>$area</td>";
            if(!$second[$area]) continue;
            foreach($second[$area] as $key => $areaData){

                echo "<td>$areaData</td>";
            }

            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    ?>


</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение.

Comment: Большое спасибо!